# How do I insert multiple inputs via a variable/defined term and get multiple outputs with a code? (Python)

Tags: python

I'm trying to make my basic syllable counter run through multiple words, but I do not know how to do so without error. In the code below, I made a placeholder variable containing two words for the code to count syllables of. However, the code ends up not functioning and creates no output. Anyone know what to do?

```
new_variable = "WORD", "AGAIN"

def syllable_count(word):
    word = word.lower()
    count = 0
    vowels = "aeiouy"
    if word[0] in vowels:
        count += 1
    for index in range(1, len(word)):
        if word[index] in vowels and word[index - 1] not in vowels:
            count += 1
    if word.endswith("e"):
        count -= 1
    if word.endswith("le"):
        count += 1
    if word.endswith("ia"):
        count += 1
    if count == 0:
        count += 1
    if word.endswith("management"):
        count -= 1
    if word.endswith("announcement"):
        count -= 1
    return count


print(syllable_count(new_variable))
```

Comment: Well, your code doesn't work because you're passing a tuple to code that expects a string.  Try `for w in new_variable:` / `print(syllable(count(w))`.

Comment: @TimRoberts When I do that, it only reads the word "again" as 1 syllable instead of 2 like it normally does.

Comment: No, it doesn't.  I replaced your last line with `for w in new_variable:` / `print(w,syllable_count(w))`, and I get "WORD 1", "AGAIN 2".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @TimRoberts mentioned in the comments. You are passing a tuple instead of a string to your `syllable_counter` function.

All you need to do is iterate through the tuple i.e. `new_varieble` and then call your `syllable_counter` for each value.

Just remove your last line and write these two:

```
for word in new_variable:
    print(syllable_counter(word))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new_variable = "WORD", "AGAIN"
print(new_variable)

('WORD', 'AGAIN')
```

You could try to iterate through the **list** of new_variable instead, for example:

```
for new_variable in ["WORD", "AGAIN"]:
    print(syllable_count(new_variable))
```